Why does the ASP.NET Designer View Not Reflect the Markup?
When I try to load my ASP.NET page in the Design view rather than by viewing the code or the markup, it looks all messed up:

It certainly does not look like how the markup says that it should look. Is this something to do with the Master Page vs the child pages?
When I run the site, it compiles and runs and looks just fine, no issues at all. It's just the Design view that's messed up, so I can't use the GUI at all to modify or alter the page, I have to do that only through the markup view.
Has anyone run across this below and have any solutions to this issue? This used to work years ago, but hasn't worked correctly for some time now, and I don't know when it got "messed up", so I can't quite trace it back to the moment when it went wrong.

HTML does not describe how a page looks, that's CSS. HTML markup defines the document's semantic structure, not its appearance or layout (excepting that CSS cannot yet radically restructure a document). Since we stopped using <table> for page-layout purposes over 20 years ago it meant that WYSIWYG web design tools became obsolete except as a live-preview tool. (I know you said that it used to work in older versions of VS or older versions of your project, but my point is that you need to let go of WYISWYG design tools and get-used to writing HTML/.aspx/.cshtml by hand).

"This used to work years ago, but hasn't worked correctly for some time now, and I don't know when it got "messed up"" - Fire up a VM running an older version of VS and do a git checkout of an older version of your project source-code and see if that worked.

My guess is that you're using ASP.NET-managed CSS bundling, but your last build failed, so your CSS bundle isn't available, so the designer can't style your page.

Actually, it is 100% possible for a designer to render correctly. The older designer was not HTML5 aware, and it did a poor job of dealing with css. However, the new designer is based on chrome engine, and thus does a near perfect job. However, as I stated below, the issue was this new preview engine does not correctly support drag + drop from the toolbox, and as a result, most of us have reverted back to the legacy designer. You can read about this feature here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/design-your-web-forms-apps-with-web-live-preview-in-visual-studio-2022/

Actually, the forms designer has always struggled when you introduce CSS into that design.
While I love the GUI designer, it never did a great job of rendering CSS, and as your skills improve, then you of course become far better with CSS, and that means the GUI designer becomes worse and worse.
You can try in vs2022 the new "live" preview feature. This will 100% render what you have 100% correctly, since it based on the new chrome engine.
However, the one big issue is the CSS new preview designer does not support drag + drop from the tool box. So, you have to drag + drop into the markup.
This feature is new for vs2022, and it will result in incredible rendering and fidelity for web forms.
That feature can be found here:
Tools->options->Web Forms Designer.

So, you can give the live preview a try. As I stated, the world's greatest opportunity was missed here, since the drag + drop into this new preview is not really allowed. So, this becomes a "preview" helper more then it becomes a "designer" helper.
In fact, I missed so much the toolbox drag + drop using the new live preview, that I switched backed to the Legacy Web Forms designer.
This feature is new and requires vs2022. Give it a try, it will render your page correctly without having to run the webform, but without drag + drop support, I find most revert back to the legacy designer as a result.
This thus suggests then:
You hit f5 to view the page, make changes to the markup, hit ctrl-s to save, and then hit f5 on the browser page to see the results.
I should also note that as of vs 17.9.7 this feature looks to be broken.
So, while it is most certainly possible to create a designer that renders near perfect, unfortunately the new designer is more of a preview tool then a designer tool.
